# Class attribute not reading on select tag using append function js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a dynamic table where by a click of a button it will generate a new row every time the button is pressed. Everything works as it supposed to but the class attribute in the select tag or any other input does not work properly. How do I get it to work. Any Idea??

Here is the .js code that works and adds new row on button click:

```
        $('.plusbtn12').click(function () {
            $(".quoteTable12").append('<tr><td><select class="js-select2 form-control c_solutions" name="i_solution[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one.."></select></td><td class="hidden-xs"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="i_quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity"></td><td><input class="form-control c_costing" type="text" name="i_cost[]" placeholder="Cost"></td></tr>');

            var options = "";

            $.getJSON("getSolution12.php", function (data) {

                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    options += "<option>" + data[i] + "</option>";
                }

                $('.quoteTable12 tr:last').find('.c_solutions').html("");
                $('.quoteTable12 tr:last').find('.c_solutions').append(options);
                $(".c_solutions").change();

            });
        });
```

Comment: Which class you want to add on which select tag?

Comment: class="js-select2"

Comment: Do you mean that the event attached to dynamically added elements are not working?

Comment: Yes exactly. That is what I meant

Comment: How are attaching the event? Can you show that part of the code

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding select dynamically you need to understand [**delegated events**](https://codepen.io/32bitkid/post/understanding-delegated-javascript-events)

> **Description:** *Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a
>   specific set of root elements.*

select you select class like this

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".js-select2", function() {
  console.log( "hey" );
});
```

Comment: Where would I implement the above on my code. Can you show me if possible?

Comment: This alone wont solve the problem. The event need to be binded properly using `on()` signature

Comment: @anu Right . I was about to change it

Comment: @CoderJoe : Sorry but what do you mean by where ? Can you read the link i gave you in answer